# Сохранение данных с FTP сервера

Tags: python

На сервере FTP есть данные которые ежедневно обновляются, к примеру, если сегодня данные на вчерашний день, то завтра этих данных уже не будет (как то так настроили), в связи с этим мне приходится ежедневно забирать оттуда данные и собирать где-то у себя в папке. Для этого я решил использовать скрипт, но при обновлении запроса через FTP сервер, данные в конечной папке для сохранения перезаписываются, а мне нужно что бы новые данные добавились, а именно в сохраненном ранее csv файле добавились строки с нового запроса. Вопрос, как можно реализовать такой код или что дописать в имеющемся коде?

```
ftp.cwd('/каталог/папка для сохранения файла/')
print(ftp.retrlines('LIST'))

filename = ftp.nlst()

for filename in filename:
    host_file = os.path.join(/каталог/папка для сохранения файла/, filename)
    try:
        with open(host_file, 'wb') as local_file:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, local_file.write)
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        pass
ftp.quit()
```

Comment: мне кажется проблема в одинаковом названии переменных в объявлении цикла "for filename in filename:". попробуйте переменную в которую получаете список файлов назвать иначе, например filenames и объявить цикл for filename in filenames:

Comment: спасибо за комментарии, но увы , это не помогло (, все также срабатывает и записывает поверх старого (

Comment: Каждый файл с заголовками? Ну это вам как-то вручную сшивать - читать старый и новый файл, объединять и записывать. С помощью `Pandas`, например. Я бы лучше забирал все файлы как есть, клал в подпапку с текущей датой, а объединял отдельным скриптом. Когда много файлов накопится, можно объединить и оставить только объединённую версию, а дальше от неё уже плясать. Тут продумать весь процесс нужно.

Comment: " Я бы лучше забирал все файлы как есть, клал в подпапку с текущей датой, а объединял отдельным скриптом."  А не могли бы подсказать, как мне код дополнить, чтобы ежедневно сохранять данные с текущей датой?